# Grassmann identity with Nabla operator in fluid dynamics (Euler equation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, fluid-dynamics

I stumbled across these lines / identity I don’t understand. To derive an alternative form of the Euler equation including the vorticity vector $\vec \omega = \vec \nabla \times \vec{\mathsf v}$, the author of the following lines states:

[image]

To my mind the Grassmann identity $$\vec a \times \left(\vec b \times \vec c\right) = \vec b \left( \vec a \cdot \vec c \right) - \vec c \left( \vec a \cdot \vec b \right) $$ was performed “in reverse order”. However, to me it is unclear why the author’s first term on the RHS is $$\vec \nabla \left( \frac{\vec{\mathsf v} ^2}{ 2}\right)$$ In my opinion $$\vec \nabla \left( \vec{\mathsf v} ^2\right)$$
would be the correct term.

**I am specifying my question:** If I simply set $\vec a = \vec c = \vec{\mathsf v}$ and $\vec b = \vec \nabla $ and naively apply the identity it will yield: \begin{align}
 \vec{\mathsf v} \times \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec{\mathsf v} \right) &= \vec \nabla \left( \vec{\mathsf{v}} \cdot \vec{\mathsf v}\right)-\vec{\mathsf{v}}\left(\vec{\mathsf v}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\right)
\\ &= \vec{\nabla}\left(\vec{\mathsf{v}}^2\right) - \left(\vec{\mathsf v}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right) \vec{\mathsf v}
\end{align}

What's the error in the prior proceeding?

Comment: It is easy to check constants with an example. Say $v=(x,0,0)$. This is a gradient $v=\nabla x^2/2$ so LHS is zero. First term on rhs is $v$. Second term is $-x\partial_x x= -x$ so equals LHS and the 1/2 is correct

Comment: W/o using an example: If i set $\vec a = \vec c =  \vec{\mathsf v}$ & $\vec b =  \vec{\nabla}$ I obtain: $$ \vec{\mathsf v} \times \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec{\mathsf v} \right) = \vec \nabla \left(\vec{\mathsf v} \cdot \vec{\mathsf v} \right) -  \vec {\mathsf v}\left(\vec{\mathsf v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \right)  $$ or am I wrong?

Comment: The example proves you wrong without a doubt. That’s not to say that the example says ‘why’ you are wrong, and I haven’t checked why yet either

Comment: I’m guessing the correct ordering of operations will give you $(\nabla v)  v$ instead of $\nabla (v\cdot v)$ which has an extra 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\let\eps\epsilon (v\times( \nabla\times v))_i= \eps_{ijk}v_j(\eps_{klm} \partial_l v_m) = \eps_{kij}v_j(\eps_{klm} \partial_l v_m)=v_j (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl})\partial_lv_m=v_j \partial_i v_j -v_j\partial_jv_i$$
So the correct formula is
$$ v\times (\nabla \times v) = \sum_{j=1}^3 v_j \nabla v_j - (v\cdot\nabla )v=\nabla |v|^2/2 - (v\cdot \nabla )v$$

Note that this first term in the RHS is different from $\nabla (v_j v_j)$ by exactly a factor of 2. I believe the error was rearranging a differential operator like a vector.

Comment: Exactly, that seems to be the error. Thank you. Nevertheless, I'd like to do it the easy way without using indices or Levi-Civita tensors.

Comment: Hm. I don’t know if a more specific answer is possible. In the identity, it’s important that $abc$ appears in this precise order. Hence the correct result is $\sum _j a_j b c_j$. In the case of vectors this is $b (a\cdot c)$. But not in the case when order matters, like when b is an operator. The general result is hard to state  without indices. But you can probably replace LC tensors with your favourite careful proof of the GM identity @ManuelManUser

Comment: I guess I can accept that. I'm rather surprised that the problem isn't as trivial as I thought after the first glance @CalvinKhor

Answer (score 1):

While vector identities can be a useful mnemonic for vector calculus identities, one must still remember that $\nabla$ is not a vector and does not have to obey normal vector identities. The relevant identity is the product rule for the gradient of a dot product:
$$
\nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{B}) = \mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B}) + \mathbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}).
$$
Just let $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{v}$ and solve for $\mathbf{v}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{v})$.